# Can't save data in database help!

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I have an widnows form aplication and i can't save the data from aplication(textboxes) in the database (ms access). The  stored data is seen in the aplication, but if i open the database it's not there... so if i open the database and restart the form aplication i don't see the before inserted data .

```
 string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
         + " Data Source=save.mdb";


            OleDbConnection empConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);


            string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO zivila "
                                 + "([naziv]) "
                                 + "VALUES (@naziv)";

            OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, empConnection);

            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@naziv", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text;

            try
            {
                empConnection.Open();
                int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                empConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                textBox1.Clear();
```

Comment: Woah, strange.  Edits don't show up as edits if the original author makes them within a certain timeframe?

Comment: No path in the database filename. This means that the database is in the current directory. But what is the current directory when you run your program? In debug mode inside VS this is the BIN\DEBUG. The updated database is there.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing a square bracket `]`

Comment: i cut some coude out so... the compiler doesn't show any errors

Comment: @Simon The compiler wouldn't show any errors. It's a problem with the SQL. Although you'd think that it'd have thrown an exception on execution...

Comment: I said that the data i use is useable OK? So if i wouldn't have a bracket i would get an error before the data would be saved. I edited the question(added the ] so please leave that bracket alone.It was my mistake editing the code cous i didn't want' to put the whole code on cous it's not needed. I would just like to know why doesn't it(the data) save to my database. If i use the whole path as the datasource then the data is stored but i have to restart the aplication to make it useable and i would have to change the path of the datasource everytime i would move the aplication...

Comment: Wow, angry man! This problem might be rattling your cage but that's not the kind of attitude that's going to get anyone anywhere. See my answer for another suggestion - Access is a tricky beast.

Answer (score 0):

OleDb seems not to support named parameters.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx):

> The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters.

This may get you what you want:

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO zivila ([naziv]) VALUES (?)";
// snip
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are looking at the right database: If your database is part of your solution, it will be copied to the bin folder and the database in the build folder will be updated instead.

I agree with @tomfanning that Access does not support named parameters and question mark should be used instead.